# Join Table from different database using Herbernate in quarkus

Tags: mysql, hibernate, entity, quarkus, quarkus-panache

There is two tables in two database. I set my configuration based on Hibernate ORM Documentation.

Error message is "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No entities were found. Did you forget to annotate your Panache Entity classes with '@Entity'?" when I call it.

However, it is work when two tables in one database.

```
package wsi.model.entity.database01;

import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFound;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFoundAction;
import wsi.model.entity.database02.Address;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(schema = "database01", name = "users")
@Cacheable
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Address address;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

```
    package wsi.model.entity.database02;
    
    import javax.persistence.*;
    
    @Entity
    @Table(schema = "database02", name = "address")
    public class Address {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private int id;
    
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
```

```
# development database configuration

quarkus.datasource.db-kind = mysql
quarkus.datasource.username = root
quarkus.datasource.password =
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database01?useSSL=false&autoreconnect=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull

#quarkus.datasource."database02".db-kind = mysql
#quarkus.datasource."database02".username = root
#quarkus.datasource."database02".password =
#quarkus.datasource."database02".jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database02?useSSL=false&autoreconnect=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
#quarkus.hibernate-orm."database02".datasource=database02
#quarkus.hibernate-orm."database02".packages=wsi.model.entity.database02
```

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.quarkus'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-agroal:2.10.0.Final'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive:2.10.0.Final'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson:2.10.0.Final'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm:2.10.0.Final'
    implementation "io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache:2.10.0.Final"
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-mysql:2.10.0.Final'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-validator:8.0.0.Alpha3'
    implementation("org.jboss.logmanager:log4j2-jboss-logmanager:1.1.1.Final")
    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5:2.10.0.Final'

}

group 'org.WSE'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.compilerArgs << '-parameters'
}

compileTestJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It think that, because you are using the `packages` property, you need to set it for the default persistenceUnit as well (if you want to use the same entities):

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.packages=wsi.model.entity.database01
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. it show "Panache entities do not support being attached to several persistence units"

Moreover, Users entity is got from database01. Is this setting changed database connect?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to use the same entities type for both databases?

Comment: users in database01
address in databse02

Comment: I don't think you can create an association with two entities that are in different dbs with Hibernate ORM

Comment: But there is Multiple persistence units to get data, right?

Or any misunderstanding for me?

https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#multiple-persistence-units


If not, what is the key word should I search to do so?

Comment: Yes, but you cannot create an association between entities in different databases (I think). What it means is that you can use two different factories. You can use one to access entities in db1 and the other  to access entities in db2.

Comment: Basically, if `User` and `Adress` are in different dbs, you won't be able to define a one-to-many (or similar) between them.

Comment: thank you. but what is Multiple persistence units? is not a function to get data from different database?

Comment: I mean implementations of `EntityManagerFactory`. Basically what's explained here: https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#cdi-integration

Comment: Is it even possible to add constraints spanning different dbs? How would you guarantee that the `address_id` in `User` matches one of the ids in `Address`? What about bridge tables (`User_Address` for example)? What about transactions? What are your requirements? Are you sure you need multiple dbs?

Comment: Yes. There are multiple dbs now. I need to create a new API for it. User.address_id matchs address.id.

Comment: I get it, but that's not a db constraint. You probably read the user with one entityManager, and then check if the associated address exists in the other db using a different EntityManager. The operation is done by the app, not the db (I assume).

Comment: Or maybe you are using different schemas? You can specify that on the entity using `@Table`:  `@Table(schema="schema1")`

Comment: yes There are different schemas. If I ignore the "database02" property, it shows missing table in database02. If I keep the below property. it shows @ OneToOne or @ ManyToOne on wsi.model.entity.database01.Users.addressId references an unknown entity: wsi.model.entity.database02.Address

Comment: I think it might work if you define a single datasource in the application.properties in the configuratio but annotate the entities with the two separate schemas using `@Table`

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'database01.address' doesn't exist

I have edited my question part following your @Table setting. Still cannot change schema.